# Quotienting by a point gives an equal space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and take $P$ to be any point of $X$. Consider the quotient space 
$X/P$, I'm asking if $X/P$ is equal to $X$ or it is just homeomorphic to $X$.
My guess is that it is equal as $X$ and $X/P$ are equal as sets and the topology does not change.

Comment: What do you mean "quotient by a point"? Quotient spaces in general topology are by an equivalence relation.

Comment: @ConnorHarris quotient by a set $A$ is using the equivalence relation with classes $\{A\} \cup \{\{x\}: x \notin A\}$, identifying $A$ to a new point. Here I assumed we're using a singleton $A = \{p\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ and $X/P$ are not the same as sets, but easily identifiable:

$X/P = \{\{x\}: x \in X\}$ ,the set of classes, which are all singletons.

And $q[O] = \hat{O} = \{\{x\}: x \in O\}$ is open whenever $O \subset X$ is, as $q^{-1}[\hat{O}] = O$, and $q$ becomes open,continuous and a bijection (as we make no identifications really), so a homeomorphism.

Comment: If i'm following, you are saying that they are not equal as sets because an element in $X$ is a point $x$ but an element in $X/P$ is a singleton $\{x\}$. So we can say that $X/P$ is the set of singletons of elements of $X$. But in  $X/P$ a singleton is also a point in $X/P$, I really don't get the difference between $X$ and $X/P$ as sets.

Comment: @palio yes that's the gist of it

Comment: $x \neq \{x\}$, even formally (if you believe the axiom of regularity/wellfoundedness).